# element required conditioning in jaxb

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd

I need to write a **jaxb class** where i need to put a condition like, if an attribute value is **"abc"** then an element is required otherwise it is not required. example :

```
<element attr1="abc">
  <property attr2="xyz"/> (required as attr1="abc")
</element>

<element attr1="def">
 </element>
```

Can anyone suggest me the possible syntax? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML structural dependencies on content cannot be expressed by XML Schema, not even with facets that are intended ro provide some constraints on content. This means that there is no automatism that would make either JAXB or schema validation throw an exception if such a condition is violated.

You'll have to write some check methods and call them after unmarshalling.